# signalR failed connection to remote server

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I experimented signalr using an example on

```
[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/78d182/signalr-sample-chat-application-in-C-Sharp/]
```

It worked fine on localhost within visual studio environment. 
I separated the server side code and uploaded on a remote server. Now when i try to connect with that remote server it is throwing these exceptions:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> Uncaught Type
>   Error: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined connect.js :9

my code is as in a connect.js file as following block of code

```
$(function () {
    alert('i m here');
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://info2gsm.com";
    var IWanaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;
    IWanaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
    $("#listMessages").append('<li>' + message + '</li>');

    };

    $("#sendMessage").click(function(){
    alert($('#txtMessage').val());
    IWanaChat.server.send($('#txtMessage').val());
    });

    $.connection.hub.start();

});
```

my HTML page is as following block

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-         scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js"></script>

    <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/connect.js"></script>

        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>

     <div id="listMessages">

        <input type="text" ID="txtMessage"></>
        <br />
        <input  id="sendMessage" type="button" value="Send" /><br />
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Are you able to hit the signalR hub when you try to hit the URL?

Comment: yes i can do it. the problem was enabling the cross domain access in web.config which i did by adding following in <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your virtual directory is not picking up the signalR hub. Can you try below?

```html
    <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```